# Como salvar os dados do form somente se vier de determinado site?

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, tenho um form que está sendo usado em outro site e salvando no meu banco de dados, através de uma action php que está no meu servidor. Mas gostaria de apenas salvar os dados caso o form venha do domínio deste site. Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode verificar o domínio remetente assim:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; // http://www.exemplo....
```

Mas tenho a avisar de que isso é um parametro editável na requisição, pode-se 'falsificar':

```
if($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] != 'url autorizado') {
    echo 'URL inválido';
    die();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. No caso do HTTP_REFERER ele pega a url toda, certo? Existe um jeito de fazer uma verificação por domínio do site? Pois o form vai aparecer em outras páginas também

Comment: Ah, fiz usando parse_url para verificar o domínio. Vlw de novo pela resposta!

Comment: De nada @cpbox .